# How display image in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

**I store image in public folder** now i want to display the image i give the path but image not show any one help me whats the wrong in my code

My image complete path is public/admin/product

```
<img src="public/admin/product/<?php echo $productr['image'];  ?>" height="30px" width="30px">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel view files blade.php supports `{{}}` tags to display values.

`{{ $valueToBeDisplayed }}`

In your case, you can do like

```
<img src="/admin/product/{{ $product['image'] }}" height="30px" width="30px" />
```

Assuming image name is abc.png.

Make sure you have that image in folder public/admin/product/abc.png

Answer (score 3):

First thing, you should not store those images inside public directory. Instead you should use **Storage** directory. Please have a look to the Laravel documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/structure#the-storage-directory

So, upload such images inside "storage/app/public"

Then fire below artisan command to create symbolic link:

**php artisan storage:link**

And then create a link to that image:

```
<img src="{{ echo asset('storage/file.png') }}" height="30px" width="30px">
```

Comment: in this folder my images are secure?

Comment: Please define secure. So, you don't want to make those images publicly available/visible?

Comment: It doesn't need the echo keyword. It works when I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

remove public from your path.., also, you might have typos on the variable $productr, (did you mean $product?) try

```
<img src="admin/product/<?php echo $product['image'];  ?>" height="30px" width="30px">
```

or, using blade standard:

```
 <img src="admin/product/{{ $product['image']; }}" height="30px" width="30px">
```

Comment: and i store image in storage folder then how we display

Comment: you can't show images from storage folder, you have to put it on public folder for it to be accessible.. if you're on linux, you can create a symlink to a folder inside public

Comment: but i do not want to show images public then how i secure my images ?

Comment: you can't secure them.. all images must be served from public path.. if you absolutely must secure them you can serve through a dynamic script that would generate it through an authenticated API.. you'll have to build that though.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if ($productr['image'])
<img src="{{ asset('images/profile/'.$productr['image']) }}" alt="{{ $category->user->image }}">
@else
<img src="{{ asset('assets/dist/img/default-150x150.png') }}" >
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{storage/app/images/.($employee -> image)}}" width="50px">
```

**"storage/app/images/"** is the folder path to where your images are stored.

Answer (score -1):

hope this will help

```
{{ asset('public/imagepath/image_name') }}
```

Comment: can you provide some explanation and context for your answer?

Comment: if you use asset, no need to add the 'public' inside the asset.